# sapply doesn't return (numeric) vector when calculating gradients

Tags: r, sapply

I am calculating gradient values by using

```
  DF$gradUx <- sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i) ((DF$V4[i+1])-DF$V4[i]), simplify = "vector")
```

but when checking `class(DF$gradUx)`, I still get a list. What I want is a numeric vector. What am I doing wrong?

```
Browse[1]> head(DF)
  V1 V2            V3           V4      
1  0  0 -2.913692e-09 2.913685e-09                          
2  1  0  1.574589e-05 3.443367e-09 
3  2  0  2.111406e-05 3.520451e-09 
4  3  0  2.496275e-05 3.613013e-09 
5  4  0  2.735775e-05 3.720385e-09 
6  5  0  2.892444e-05 3.841937e-09
```

Comment: you get a list because not all elements returned are the same size (the first and last I guess). You might be better off using `rollapply` in `zoo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sapply` I should simply use `diff(DF$V3)` and write it into a new data.frame:

```
gradients = data.frame(gradUx=diff(DF$V3),gradUy=diff(DF$V4))
```

Comment: I'm all for answering your own question, but this produces a different difference than in your question. Do you mean `diff(DF$V3, lag=2)` instead? I also suggest that you accept this or one of the other answers if the question is resolved.

Comment: My mistake. The gradient should be a simple first order divided difference, thus `lag=1` and in the question `DF$V4[i+1]-DF$V4[i]` (corrected).

Answer (score 2):

You will only get a numeric vector when all return values are of length 1. More accurately, you will get an array if all return values are the same length. From `?sapply` "Details":

> Simplification in 'sapply' is only attempted if 'X' has length
>   greater than zero and if the return values from all elements of
>   'X' are all of the same (positive) length.  If the common length
>   is one the result is a vector, and if greater than one is a matrix
>   with a column corresponding to each element of 'X'.

When `i == 0`, your formula will return `numeric(0)`, so the whole return will be a list.

You need to change your calculation to account for indexing outside the bounds of your vector. `DF$V4[1-1]` returns `numeric(0)`, and `DF$V4[nrow(DF)+1]` returns `NA`. Fix this logic and you should remedy the vector problem.

**Edit**: for historical reasons, the original question incorrectly calculated the difference as `DF$V4[i+1])-DF$V4[i-1]`, giving a lag-2 difference, whereas the recently-edited question (and the OP's intent) shows a lag-1 difference.

Answer (score 0):

This calculation can be vectorized very easily if you line up the observations. I use `head` and `tail` to drop the first 2 and last 2 observations:

`gradUx <- c(NA, tail(df$V4, -2) - head(df$V4, -2), NA)`

```
> gradUx
[1]          NA 6.06766e-10 1.69646e-10 1.99934e-10 2.28924e-10          NA
```

Which provides the same values as your approach, in vector form:

```
> sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) ((df$V4[i+1])-df$V4[i-1]), simplify = "vector")
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 6.06766e-10

[[3]]
[1] 1.69646e-10

[[4]]
[1] 1.99934e-10

[[5]]
[1] 2.28924e-10

[[6]]
[1] NA
```